# Calling Excel Macro from PowerShell without file name

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm trying to run a program in Powershell where I monitor and folder for new xlsm files and, when a new file is added to the folder, a macro will be run that is embedded in the file. This file is an order form which is sent out to clients with macro already included. The problem I have is that although the macro will always have the same name, the file may have a different name, when sent in. This code works fine when I specify the name of the file, however, when trying to attempt to just call the latest file, it tells me that the macro cannot be found. Code below, any help would appreciated, thanks.

```
`
###

   # create an Excel.Application object
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

# set the Visible property to $false so that Excel is not visible
$excel.Visible = $false

# specify the path to the folder to monitor
$path = "Path/to/directory"

# specify the name of the macro to run
$macroName = "Macro_Name"

# create an empty array to store the list of existing files
$files = @()

# create an infinite loop
while ($true) {
    # get the list of files in the folder
    $newFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter *.xlsm | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
    $latest = (Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter *.xlsm | Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime | select -First 1)
    $latest_filename = $latest.Name

    # compare the list of files with the previous list
    $addedFiles = Compare-Object $files $newFiles | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq "=>" } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject

    # if there are added files, then run the macro
    if ($addedFiles) {
        # path to the macro file to be run
        $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($latest_filename)

        # run the macro in the Excel workbook
        $excel.Run("$macroName")


        # close the Excel workbook
        $workbook.Close()

        # update the list of files
        $files = $newFiles
    }

    # wait for 10 seconds before checking the folder again
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
}

# close the Excel.Application object when the script ends
$excel.Quit()`
```

Answer (score 0):

Just from a security standpoint, I don't think that sending out files with macros to customers is a good idea. Some may have restrictions on running them and then your order form wouldn't work.

I don't think this is the right way to approach this whole scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your concern but, unfortunately, unavoidable. It's something that we have been doing for quite some time, already. This is just a means to automate some of the process.